# Unable to reference public Lambda ARN layer when publishing via boto3

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I have a public ARN layer that I wish to use in deploying a Lambda function.

The relevant snippet of my code is below:

```
LAMBDA_ARN_LAYER = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:012345678901:layer:canedge-influxdb-writer-2:5"

lambda_client = session.client("lambda")

lambda_client.create_function(
    FunctionName=LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME,
    Runtime=PYTHON_BUILD,
    Role=LAMBDA_ROLE_ARN,
    Handler=LAMBDA_HANDLER,
    Code={"ZipFile": open(f"{LAMBDA_ZIP_FILE}.zip", "rb").read()},
    Timeout=180,
    MemorySize=1024,
    Layers=[LAMBDA_ARN_LAYER],
)
```

When I run this with my own account (which I also used to create and publish the ARN layers), it works as it should. However, if I try to deploy the Lambda function with a different account, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: User: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/XXX is not authorized to perform: lambda:GetLayerVersion on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:012345678901:layer:canedge-influxdb-writer-2:5 because no resource-based policy allows the lambda:GetLayerVersion action
```

What is strange is that I can "manually" go into my Lambda function with the same user and add the ARN layer and it works as it should, so it appears to be public.

When I created the Lambda ARN layer originally, I used below code (in a Python script referencing the AWS CLI via subprocess:

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --region {region} --layer-name {layer_name} --description "{layer_description}" --cli-connect-timeout 6000 --license-info "MIT" --zip-file "fileb://canedge-influxdb-writer.zip" --compatible-runtimes python3.9

aws lambda add-layer-version-permission --layer-name {layer_name} --version-number {version} --statement-id allAccountsExample --principal * --action lambda:GetLayerVersion --region {region}
```

The user I am trying to deploy with has the default admin access rights:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing in the above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not explicitly define the `region_name` when setting up the boto3 client initially. After fixing this, the problem was resolved.